# What's a negative personality trait that describes one's desire to be perfect? Also, a word for someone that is too forgiving

Tags: personality

Thanks in advance, guys. 
If anyone's got a term for someone that is always blaming themselves, that would be pretty sweet as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the word Perfectionist.

RELATED WORDS (more negative):
quibbler, fusspot, purist, formalist, fussbudget